# Hash function for sequences of tuples - Duplicate elimination

Tags: c++, algorithm, hash, cuda

I want to eliminate duplicates of sequences of tuples. These sequences look like this:

```
1. (1,1)(2,5,9)(2,3,10)(2,1)
2. (1,2)(3,2,1)(2,5,9)(2,1)
3. (1,1)(2,5,9)(2,3,10)(2,1)
4. (2,1)(2,3,10)(2,5,9)(1,1)
5. (2,1)(2,3,10)(1,1)
6. (1,1)(2,5,9)(2,3,10)(2,2)
```

The number of entries per tuple varies as does the number of tuple per sequence. Since I have lots of sequences which I ultimately want to deal with in parallel using CUDA, I thought that calculating a hash per sequence would be an efficient way to identify duplicate sequences.

**How would such a `hash` function be implemented?**
And: How big is the collision probability of two different sequences producing the same final hash value?

I have two requirements which I am not sure if they can be fulfilled:

a) Can such a hash be calculated on the fly?
I want to avoid the storage of the full sequences, therefore I'd like to do something like this:

```
h = 0; // init hash
...
h = h + hash(1,1);
...
h = h + hash(2,5,9);
...
h = h + hash(2,3,10)
... 
h = h + hash(2,1)
```

where `+` is any operator which combines hashes of tuples.

b) Can such a hash be independent of the "direction" of the sequence?
In the above example sequences `1.` and `4.` consist of the same tuples but the order is reversed, but I like to identify them as duplicates.

Comment: This doesn't really read like a CUDA programming question. You need a hash function or algorithm first, then comes implementation details. The bold question sounds like a master's thesis sized question by itself.

Comment: @talonmies I only tagged it "CUDA" since this implementational "detail" might impose some restrictions.

Comment: One way of making the hash independent of ordering is sorting the sequences according to some appropriate ordering before hashing. The default ordering for std tuples is lexicographical, similar to string ordering.

Comment: @ErikAlapää that would require that I store the full sequence, sort and hash at the end. I'd rather not do that due to memory concerns as pointed out in the question.

Comment: @Cicada I don't want to invent one, I am looking for a suitable one which fits my requirements.

Comment: @Cicada Is there an accumulation that generates the same hash value for (a,b,c) and (c,b,a)?

Comment: @m.s. Yes there is. Hash both tuples once in right to left and once in left to right order. Combine the first right to left with the second right to left and the first left to right with the second left to right. If those hashes equal then you found a structure like (a,b,c) <-> (c,b,a)

Answer (score 2):

For hashing you can use `std::hash<std::size_t>` or whatever (unsigned) integer type you use. The collision probability is somewhere around `1.0/std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()`, which is very small. To make the usability a bit better you can write your own tuple hasher:

```
namespace hash_tuple
{   
std::size_t hash_combine(std::size_t l, std::size_t r) noexcept
{
    constexpr static const double phi = 1.6180339887498949025257388711906969547271728515625;

    static const double val = std::pow(2ULL, 4ULL * sizeof(std::size_t));

    static const std::size_t magic_number = val / phi;

    l ^= r + magic_number + (l << 6) + (l >> 2);
    return l;
}

template <typename TT>
struct hash
{
    std::size_t operator()(TT const& tt) const noexcept
    {                                              
    return std::hash<TT>()(tt);                                 
    }                                              
};

namespace
{
    template <class TupleT, std::size_t Index = std::tuple_size<TupleT>::value - 1ULL>
    struct HashValueImpl
    {
    static std::size_t apply(std::size_t seed, TupleT const& tuple) noexcept
    {
        seed = HashValueImpl<TupleT, Index - 1ULL>::apply(seed, tuple);
        seed = hash_combine(seed, std::get<Index>(tuple));

        return seed;
    }
    };

    template <class TupleT>
    struct HashValueImpl<TupleT, 0ULL>
    {
    static std::size_t apply(size_t seed, TupleT const& tuple) noexcept
    {
        seed = hash_combine(seed, std::get<0>(tuple));
        return seed;
    }
    };
}

template <typename ... TT>
struct hash<std::tuple<TT...>> 
{
    std::size_t operator()(std::tuple<TT...> const& tt) const noexcept
    {                                              
    std::size_t seed = 0;                             
    seed = HashValueImpl<std::tuple<TT...> >::apply(seed, tt);    
    return seed;                                 
    }                                              
};
}
```

Thus you can write code like

```
using hash_tuple::hash;
auto mytuple = std::make_tuple(3, 2, 1, 0);
auto hasher = hash<decltype(mytuple)>();

std::size_t mytuple_hash = hasher(mytuple);
```

To fulfill your constraint `b` we need for each tuple 2 hashes, the normal hash and the hash of the reversed tuple.
So at first we need to deal with how to reverse one:

```
template<typename T, typename TT = typename std::remove_reference<T>::type, size_t... I>
auto reverse_impl(T&& t, std::index_sequence<I...>)
-> std::tuple<typename std::tuple_element<sizeof...(I) - 1 - I, TT>::type...>
{
    return std::make_tuple(std::get<sizeof...(I) - 1 - I>(std::forward<T>(t))...);
}

template<typename T, typename TT = typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>
auto reverse(T&& t)
-> decltype(reverse_impl(std::forward<T>(t),
                    std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<TT>::value>()))
{
    return reverse_impl(std::forward<T>(t),
                    std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<TT>::value>());
}
```

Then we can calculate our hashes

```
auto t0 = std::make_tuple(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
auto t1 = std::make_tuple(6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1);

using hash_tuple::hash;
auto hasher = hash<decltype(t0)>();

std::size_t t0hash = hasher(t0);
std::size_t t1hash = hasher(t1);

std::size_t t0hsah = hasher(reverse(t0));
std::size_t t1hsah = hasher(reverse(t1));
```

And if `hash_combine(t0hash, t1hash) == hash_combine(t1hsah, t0hsah)` you found what you want. You can apply this "inner-tuple-hashing-mechanic" to the hashes of many tuples pretty easily. Play around with this [online](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b688a67055bf8810)!

Comment: is it possible to implement the "reverse equality hash checking" without explicitly having to store the full tuple? Can I somehow create both hashes (the forward and the backward one) incrementally and compare at the end?

Comment: @m.s. Well somehow you need to process (mean: hash each element and combine all of those to one)  all elements of your tuple in the right order. You can do that without saving a explicit tuple, but you would obviously need many more file-accesses. (which is not that fast)